# Linux Kernel task_struct void *stack

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, process, linux-kernel

What is the `void *stack` declaration in `task_struct` in [sched.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h)?

Is it the pointer to the process image (stack, heap, .bss, data, text) stack? If so, where are the pointers to the rest of the process image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux kernel source code you can see the macros [task_thread_info()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/sched.h#L2826):

```
#define task_thread_info(task)  ((struct thread_info *)(task)->stack)
```

**The `void *stack` pointer of `task_struct` points to `thread_info`**.

Since 2.6 version Linux uses part of a task's kernel-stack page-frame to store "thread information" (`thread_info`). The `thread_info` in its turn includes a pointer to the `task_struct`:

```
struct task_struct *task = info->task;
```

F.e. (for platforms where the stack grows in the direction of decreasing the value of the memory address):

[image]

Useful links: [1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=2ahUKEwiawZbH6Y7mAhXqwsQBHTIYDvUQFjAJegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.usfca.edu%2F~cruse%2Fcs635%2Flesson05.ppt&usg=AOvVaw1abTPEZQxU8QnEFnUX0Xpz), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22372/what-is-the-need-of-the-struct-thread-info-in-locating-struct-task-struct)

---

> where are the pointers to the rest of the process image?

Such info is contained in *memory descriptor* [`mm_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L392). F.e.:

```
struct mm_struct {
    //...
    unsigned long start_code, end_code, start_data, end_data;
    unsigned long start_brk, brk, start_stack;
    //...
}
```

Must-read: [How The Kernel Manages Your Memory](https://manybutfinite.com/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/)